# PHP exec() has write permission error despite write privilege

Tags: permissions, apache2, php, c, executable

I am running 7.0.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, under LAMP, on two Ubuntu 16.04. The C code, to open the file for writing is:

```
 #define ERROR_OPENING_FILE -4

 fprintf(stderr, "Open output file: /var/www/dropbox/candidates_results.lst.");
 if (!(fpOutputFile=fopen("/var/www/dropbox/candidates_results.lst", "w"))){
       perror("Error opening output file: ");
       throw ERROR_OPENING_FILE;
 }
```

I call the executable, from PHP, with the following.

```
    $program="/var/www/executables/programName ";
    $inFile="/var/www/dropbox/candidates.lst";
    $str=$program . " -i " . $inFile;
    $Result=exec($str, $output, $return);
```

After refreshing the web page, I go to the linux shell and enter

```
cat /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

This returns

```
Open output file: /var/www/dropbox/candidates_results.lst.
Error opening output file: : Permission denied
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'int'
Aborted (core dumped)
```

When I enter

```
ls -l /var/www/dropbox/candidates_results.lst
```

I get

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu www 107 May 20 11:40 /var/www/dropbox/candidates_results.lst
```

The problem goes away if I enter

```
sudo chmod o+w /var/www/dropbox/candidates_results.lst
```

so the long listing becomes

```
-rw-rw-rw- 1 ubuntu www 107 May 20 11:40 /var/www/dropbox/candidates_results.lst
```

However, www-data is a member of the www group

```
 $ grep '^www' /etc/group
 www-data:x:33:
 www:x:1001:ubuntu
```

So it seems that www-data should have group permissions.  I do not see why I get the write permission error after entering

```
sudo chmod o-w /var/www/dropbox/candidates_results.lst
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> $ grep '^www' /etc/group
>   www-data:x:33:
>   www:x:1001:ubuntu
> ```

This clearly shows that `www-data` is not a member of the www group. Only `ubuntu` is member of `www` group.

Run

```
sudo usermod -a -G www www-data
```

to add `www-data` to `www`-group, and restart the webserver.